# PHP Time Addition

Tags: php, time, addition

I am working on timesheet for my employees where I am getting daily total hours.
I would like to calculate total working hours from this table.

I am having MySQL Column with total hours.

Total Hours
10:15:00
8:00:00
7:20:00
6:30:00

Please help how do I calculate this total monthly hours.

Comment: Use Sum() to get the total. Select sum(colomn) from table where colomnNameEmploye="nameEmploye"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to calculate sum of time field

```
SELECT  
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( 
`your_column_name` ) ) ) AS 
timeSum  
FROM YourTableName
```